# Openerp 7- how to run datetime update query

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

I am having problem with this update query and I don't understand the error here. please help me to solve this.

**Field**

```
'sign_in' : fields.datetime("Sign In"),
```

**Variable**

```
sgn_in1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(sign_in, DATETIME_FORMAT1).time()
```

**Query**

```
cr.execute("""UPDATE allowance.attendances SET sign_in = %s WHERE id =%s"""%(sign_in1,colmn_id))
```

**Error**

> ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ":" LINE 1: UPDATE
>   allowance.attendances SET sign_in = 08:15:00

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query should be like this,

```
cr.execute("UPDATE allowance_attendances SET sign_in = '%s' WHERE id =%s"%(sign_in1,colmn_id))
```

Datetime / time / date value must be passed in single quote. For integer / long it's not required.

While you execute direct query in database then the odoo model doesn't contains . (dot) in name, it's only allowed to use while you perform operation via odoo ORM methods.

so Model shouldn't be **allowance.attendances**, it should be **allowance_attendances**

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and those single quotes did the magic. Thanks again